# @AfterReturning from ExceptionHandler not working

Tags: spring-aop

I have a GlobalExceptionHandler class which contain multiple methods annotated with @ExceptionHandler.

```java
@ExceptionHandler({ AccessDeniedException.class })
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccessDeniedException(
  Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
      "Access denied message here", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

I have a AOP which is suppose to be triggered after the exception handler returns response.

```java
@AfterReturning(value="@annotation(exceptionHandler)",returning="response")  
public void afterReturningAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object response) {
//do something
}
```

But the @AfterReturning is not triggered after the handler returns a valid response.

Tried full qualified name but not working

```java
@AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler)", returning = "response"){
public void afterReturningAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object response) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: You should use the fully qualified name for annotation, `@AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler)", returning = "response")`.

Comment: tried but still not working

Comment: Please also include the class containing `afterReturningAdvice` method.

Comment: @KiranKumar , the code works for me. Chances are , you have missed annotating the advice class with `@Aspect` . If  this is not a `spring-boot` project , do confirm if you have enabled Spring AOP with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`

Comment: This is a spring boot project, I have used `@Aspect`. I have other methods in same controller advice class with different annotations which are working with aspect. The issue is only with methods having annotation `@ExceptionHandler`

Comment: @KiranKumar , I copied the code shared with your question and the advice worked in my test project. Please confirm if the aspect class is autodetected by Spring container through component scan. If all these are correct , please share the entire controller , controller advice , aspect code or a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Thanks a lot your hint worked, when I posted this question I didn't pasted the actual code  . I tried the one I pasted and compared. The difference is my exception handler method is marked final. I removed final and it worked

Comment: @R.G, would you like to write an answer, explaining why Spring AOP does not work with final target methods, so the OP can accept it and close the question? I don't want to steal your reputation. Kiran: It is a bad idea to modify code after copying it. Rather switch to a new Git branch, modify the code (e.g. renaming confidential package and class names, removing code unnecessary to reproduce the problem), test if it still reproduces the problem in the same way, make a commit (so you can later switch to that branch again and test the answer) and then post here. Our job is all about details.

Comment: @kriegaex , sure . I have added the answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-proxying) to understand the proxying mechanisms in Spring framework.

Assuming the `ExceptionHandler` code written was of the following format

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class TestControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler({ AccessDeniedException.class })
    final public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccessDeniedException(
      Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
          "Access denied message here", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

key points from the documentation pertaining to the question are

1. Spring AOP uses either JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB to create the
   proxy for a given target object.
2. If the target object to be proxied implements at least one
   interface, a JDK dynamic proxy is used. All of the interfaces
   implemented by the target type are proxied. If the target object
   does not implement any interfaces, a CGLIB proxy is created.
3. With CGLIB, final methods cannot be advised, as they cannot be overridden in runtime-generated subclasses.

- OP identified the issue based on the comments and hints , this answer is for any future references.